# Should HeapFree be used after HeapReAlloc changes memory address?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory

Assume following scenario:

1. We allocate a block of memory using *HeapAlloc()* WINAPI function to var **X**
2. We want to reallocate X using *HeapRealloc()*
3. *HeapRealloc()* resizes the heap and moves to new location, therefore pointer has been changed - let's call it **Y**

Should we do *HeapFree* on the old memory address (X) after it has been moved by *HeapReAlloc* or will *HeapReAlloc* automatically clean up previous memory pointer for us?

Answer (score 3):

No. HeapReAlloc() will have already freed the old address. Virtually every allocator you'll come across does this, whether it's the Windows API heap functions or the standard C malloc()/realloc()/free(). Here's a direct quote from [the HeapReAlloc() documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), though, for good measure:

> If HeapReAlloc fails, the original memory is not freed, and the original handle and pointer are still valid.
>
> HeapReAlloc is guaranteed to preserve the content of the memory being reallocated, even if the new memory is allocated at a different location. The process of preserving the memory content involves a memory copy operation that is potentially very time-consuming.

These combined should lead to the conclusion that HeapReAlloc() frees the old memory address if successful.

Comment: And for good measure, when calling `HeapReAlloc()`, DO NOT assign the result directly to your original variable. If the reallocation fails, the old memory will still be valid but you will have lost your pointer to it, thus leaking that memory.  Be sure to always reallocate to a temp variable first, and then assign the value to the original variable only if the reallocation was successful.